# Change the background color of header in a UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, xcode4.2

I am trying to change the background color of the header in the UITableViewController, which actually has it's own *.h/m file.    I my .m file, I pasted the following code as suggested by several stackoverflow answers:

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 30)];
    if (section == 0)
        [headerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    else 
        [headerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    return headerView;
}
```

But the result is the following:

[image]

I want the blue header to be red.  I don't understand why there is a red bar between the header and the first cell.

**Additional Details**
In case this comment is useful: I'm new to xcode 4.2. What I did was go to storyboard, drag a navigation controller, drag a table view. Go to left hand explorer bard and add a new file with name MyUITableViewController that extends UITableviewController. Pasted my function above into the MyUITabelViewController.m file. Then i implemented the heightforheaderinsection funciton to return a CGfloat value (and all that did afterwards was increase the space between the blue header and the first cell).  Go back to storyboard, left click my tableviewcontroller and make sure it points to my MyUITableViewController class. What steps am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple's UITableViewDelegate class reference, on method `- tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`:

> This method only works correctly when tableView:heightForHeaderInSection: is also implemented.

Did you implement that method?

**EDIT:** after read your comments, and knowing that you're using storyboard, you have an easy way to create a custom background for the whole table:

1) Create a TableViewController on your storyboard

2) Drag a UIView:

[image: UIView]

3) Drop the UIView into your table view's header, here:

[image: Dropping view into tableView header]

4) You have now a view on the header that you can resize, change color, add, e.g., an UILabel...:

[image: TableView with header]
[image: header with label]

Comment: I tired implementing heightForheaderinsection, but all that did was increase the spacing between the blue header and the first cell.  How do i override the color fo teh blue header?

Comment: But what table view do you want?? Can you write here the order of your elements (I mean, e.g.: red UIView (30px), table section title, cell...)

Comment: I'm new to xcode 4.2, so not sure exactly what you mean.   What I did was go to storyboard, drag a navigation controller, drag a table view.   Go to left hand explorer bard and add a new file with name MyUITableViewController that extends UITableviewController.  Pasted my function above into the MyUITabelViewController.m file.  then i implemented the heightforheaderinsection funciton to return a CGfloat value.  Go back to storyboard, left click my tableviewcontroller and make sure it points to my MyUITableViewController class.  What steps am I missing?  thanks

Comment: You aren't missing any steps, but I'm asking what table do you want to get.

Comment: I mean, do you want a custom header for each section on your table or a custom header for the whole table?

Comment: I have edit my answer, showing how to add a custom header from storyboard

Answer (score 0):

Use tablview delegate method for customize tablviewheader.  I show here some code use it...

```
 -(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
  {

    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    UIImageView *tempimage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 300,34)];// you can also use image view to show your required color.
    tempimage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage.png"];
    [headerView addSubview:tempimage];
    [headerView addSubview:headername];
    return  headerView;

  }
```

Hope, this will help you..

Comment: i tried your code but it still presents the same problem mentioned in my question.  The header colour is appears between the blue header and the first cell.

Comment: you need to use custom header. I have use above code and it's work fine. Did you use UIView and UIImageView as i show you in my code.

Comment: yes, i copied your code as is and replace yourimage.png with somethign else.   headername was undefined, so i commented out that line.   Your code creates a custom header right?

Answer (score -1):

The blue header shown is the navigation controller header.